How to solve NestJS UndefinedDependencyException?
My NestJS application fails to start with this error:

UndefinedDependencyException [Error]: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the FlowerService (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the FlowerModule context.


What does FlowerModule look like? What is the dependency at index zero of FlowerService looks like?

This might be caused by an import cycle. Other than breaking the cycle, a possible solution is to use forwardRef with Inject:
@Injectable()
export class FlowerService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => SoilService)) // <-- add this line
    private readonly soilService: SoilService
  ) { }

  // ...
}

See https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency

You should really, really try to avoid circular dependencies.
